# If I take mean of uncertain observations what happens to SD of the observations?

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, measurement-error, measurement

I have some observations, each with an accompanying standard deviation (shown here as error bars):

[image]

I want to make a summarised plot of this data by taking mean of all observations for a given X value, so something like this:

[image]

I'm confused how I will calculate the standard deviation for these averaged measurements. Will it be just the mean of the std. devs of all observations for a given X?

Comment: First, what is the formula for your 'error bars'.

Comment: @BruceET they're just standard deviations as I mention. So it's the point +- SD

Comment: OK, but such 'error bars' can often be misleading (understating the variability of the mean), which I fear may be a major reason for their continued use. // If $SD(X) = \sigma_x,$ $SD(Y) = \sigma_y,$ and $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $SD(X+Y) = \sqrt{\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2}.$ Maybe that is useful in your situation, which I do not fully understand.

Comment: Alright, then what would be a similar formula for $SD(X/n)$. I think I can use this along with the formula for $SD(X+Y)$ to get the SD for my averaged values.

Comment: Not clear what you're doing. Suppose you have sample mean $\bar X$ based on $m$ observations and $\bar Y$ based on $n$ observations. Are you dealing with $\bar X + \bar Y.$ with,.$5(\bar X + \bar Y),$ or with $(n\bar X + m\bar Y)/(n+m).$? // Also not clear whether your error bars are based on the SD $S$ or on the estimated standard error $S/\sqrt{n}.$

Answer (score 1):

First, before dealing with combinations of two samples, here are some methods for displaying variability of a *single* sample. Suppose you have a random sample of size $n=50$ from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 70, \sigma=4),$ as simulated in R below:

```
set.seed(616)
x = round(rnorm(50, 70, 4), 2)
x
 [1] 79.76 72.52 68.73 72.78 67.00 72.52 71.42 68.52 73.62 67.13
[11] 67.89 73.98 65.48 73.36 68.67 74.39 67.96 67.57 75.20 73.87
[21] 66.75 66.73 75.51 73.55 68.79 68.76 71.03 65.22 69.25 67.42
[31] 71.34 71.21 74.38 73.12 70.09 73.19 68.54 71.02 73.29 59.00
[41] 69.94 68.24 73.57 72.40 65.21 67.93 68.10 70.33 71.95 76.71
summary(x);  sd(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  59.00   68.00   70.67   70.50   73.27   79.76 
[1] 3.618636
```

One way to display the data is with a 'notched' boxplot, where the notches in the sides of the box show a nonparametric confidence interval for the population median. It is calibrated so that, roughly speaking, nonoverlapping notches from two samples indicates they are from populations with different medians. (For our data the notch includes the true population median $\eta = \mu = 70,$ but with a real-life dataset we wouldn't know the true value of $\eta$ of the population from which the data were taken.)

```
boxplot(x, notch=T, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2", pch=19)
```

[image]

A 95% *confidence* interval for $\mu$ based on the data above would be of the form $\bar X + 2.0S/\sqrt{n},$ which computes to $(69.47, 71.53).$

```
t.test(x)$conf.int
[1] 69.47039 71.52721
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

A 95% *prediction* interval for the value of the *next* ($(n+1)$st) observation from the same population is of the form $\bar X \pm S\sqrt{1+1/n}.$ For our sample this interval is $(63/19, 77.81).$

```
mean(x) + pm*2.0*sd(x)*sqrt(1 + 1/50)
[1] 63.18951 77.80809
```

Here is a stripchart of the $n = 50$ observations, with the confidence interval shown as solid green bars and the prediction interval as broken maroon bars.

```
stripchart(x, pch="|")
 abline(v=c(69.47, 71.53), col="darkgreen")
 abline(v=c(63.12, 77.81), col="maroon", lty="dashed", lwd=2)
```

[image]

*Note:* Sometimes 'error bars' are of the form $\bar X \pm S$ and sometimes
of the form $\bar X \pm S/\sqrt{n}.$ The former a are not as far apart
as the lower and upper confidence bounds; the latter are not quite as far apart as the lower and upper prediction bounds.

Comment: Your point about boxplots gave me an idea. Since all I wanted to do was display a summarised version of the original data for each X with some information about the variability visible, I'll just draw a boxplot at each X.

Comment: Your further explanation about different bounds which can be shown as 'error bars' cleared some other confusions I had. Thanks

Comment: Good idea to use boxplots, as long as you don't get the idea there is necessarily something 'wrong' with outliers. For example, [see](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/411898/boxplot-in-r-shows-wrong-outliers/411905#411905)/

Comment: Not at all. I actually prefer that the outliers are visible for my task.